# Why do I get this TypeError using the randint function in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, module, floating-point, typeerror

In a main.py file that I got from my university, which is part of an assignment, I get this error message when trying to run the main.py file:

[image]

That should not happen. I did write correct code in the places that I should. I should not be getting errors in places that I am not allowed to change. And its a problem only I am having! Other people from my class are not having this problem, even using the same code!

My Python version is: Python 3.12.1

Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) should be called with integer bounds, but 1e15 is a float.

Try instead:

```
randint(0, 10**15)
```

Since you're calling it multiple times, it might be better to use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) instead:

```
 Ai = random.choices(range(10**15 + 1), k=len(elems))
```

If you're not allowed to modify the code in `main.py`, then you should clarify with the instructor which Python version(s) should be used for this assignment, because the code in `main.py` will not work on Python 3.12 due to the removal of type coercion in [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange):

> *Changed in version 3.12*: Automatic conversion of non-integer types is no longer supported. Calls such as `randrange(10.0)` and `randrange(Fraction(10, 1))` now raise a `TypeError`.

Actually you should probably notify the instructor: mention that some guy on the internet says the code in `main.py` needs fixing for Python 3.12, and link them to this Q&A.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am not allowed to do that. I am not allowed to change anything in thw main.py as that is part of the assignment.

Comment: Well that is where the error is.  Where is your code, if not in `main.py`?

Comment: It is another file, which gets imported into main.py

Comment: The provided code is broken, but the problem wouldn't have shown up until Python 3.12, when the deprecated behavior they were triggering got changed to an error.

Comment: yep, that seems right! The problem didnt show up before I updated to 3.12. I am so sad that i go to this uni wow :(